# how to run pod install in project directory

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

A tutorial tells me to run `pod install` in the project directory. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 40):

1. Open Terminal.
2. If you haven't already done so, run this command:

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```

   Wait for it to finish before proceeding.
3. Find the project directory in the Finder. This should be the folder that has the Xcode project in it.
4. Type `cd` into the terminal, followed by a space.
5. Drag and drop the project directory into the terminal window. It should now say something like this:

   ```
   cd /Users/someone/Downloads/WonderfulProject
   ```
6. Press return.
7. Now type `pod install`. Wait for that to finish. It could take a while.

Done!

Comment: thanks for answering. i get error in step 7. it returns [!] Unable to find a target named `Parse-Sinch` after "Analysing dependencies" @tbodt

Comment: Sounds like you are having problems with understanding what a Podfile should look like, [here's the guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) on this.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial you're using? That would help with context.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting the exact same error. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the podfile. But I think it would work if you just skip that step, since there's already a Pods directory that looks correct. Have you tried doing the tutorial without running `pod install`?

Comment: You may need the pod init step before pod install if you don't already have a podfile in your project.

Comment: In my case `gem` was not working, so I had to run `brew install cocoapods` at step 2

Answer (score 21):

Close your Xcode project before you carry out the following steps.

1. First check if you have cocoapods installed. For this, type `pod --version` into the terminal and if a version no. is returned, you are good to move on to step 3.
2. If not installed, install cocoapods using the command `sudo gem install cocoapods` in terminal.
3. Next type `cd` and name of your Xcode project directory
4. Type `pod init` in terminal. This adds the podfile into your project where you can make edits.
5. Next type `pod install`.

Now, if a Podfile already exists in your Xcode project folder, for example if the tutorial already added it into the project for you, then you can just carry out step 5, provided you have cd-ed into your Xcode project directory.

Comment: pod init helped to create the default file.Thanks for this steps.

Answer (score 4):

This actually can happen because the pod install might have problems when resolving the base directory when going through dependencies. Happens especially with react-native projects.

You have two options.

1. Use cd ./dir and run pod install

   cd ./project-directory && pod install
2. Use flag for project directory pod install --project-directory=project-dir

   pod install --project-directory=project-dir

Answer (score 1):

simply go to root directory of your project in terminal and run

```
cd  ios
```

then run

```
pod install
```

hopefully it will work.