# Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

Tags: firebase, swift3, xcode8, ios10

When I compile the application I get an error equal to this:

> Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

This error appear in `import Firebase` of my file swift.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

There is only one way to solve this issue.

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete project's temp files located at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Delete `ProjectName.xcworkspace`
4. Delete `Podfile.lock` file and `Pods` folder
5. Run `pod install`.
6. Open the newly created `ProjectName.xcworkspace` file and build.

Comment: If I delete ProjectName.xcworkspace, does it delete the previous code there?

Comment: @ConsBulaquena Actually, you have to delete the `xcworkspace`, it doesn't include the code you wrote but is automatically generated by Pod, don't worry about it.

Comment: I don't have a Xcode folder I  `~/Library/Developer`

Comment: @Jonas weird, open Xcode, go to Preferences->Locations and share what you see. Check mine: https://ibb.co/dUvgk8

Comment: @DimitrisBouzikas thanks a lot! It was under `~/User/ME/Library/...` and there the Library folder was hidden. (Made it visible with Shift+cmd+(dot))

Comment: solved my problem. Note that this will delete your existing build schemes.

Comment: the first two steps worked for me. I didn't have to delete the workspace file, I just had to open it instead of the project file after quitting xcode and deleting derived data

Comment: for future readers, there is a library folder of the computer and one of the user, most of the time it is in the users one

Comment: for those who don't know how to run pod install: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418062/how-to-run-pod-install-in-project-directory

Comment: I only needed step 4 and 5

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my time! `xCode v12`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433526/7856586 if you cannot find DerivedData folder

Comment: Where are `ProjectName.xcworkspace`,  `Podfile.lock` and `Pods`?

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin in the main folder of the project. Those files are created only if you create a project and add Pods to it, if you are using SPM or don't have any library yet, then you won't have them.

Comment: You can reach **/DerivedData** folder by this :
- Open a terminal and than run this command!

`open ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 53):

**Build** (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) worked for me. (It's important to build the framework target, then build the project)

Comment: worked for me after I applied the first answer. Also had to change the FIRApp.configure() to FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: worked for me without having to apply Dimitris Bouzikas answer, and i was adding firebase to an existing project for those doing the same

Comment: I tried Dimitri's solution but it didnt work, ended up missing necessary files, this solution did fix the problem

Comment: @MarioRojas Can you determine what are the necessary files? Study a bit how Pod works.

Comment: I'd like to vote this as one of the funniest answers.

Answer (score 45):

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9. All I have to do is selecting FirebaseCore Scheme.

On Xcode:

```
Product->Scheme->FirebaseCore.
```

If you don't have FirebaseCore go to `Manage Schemes` and select it. Then try again.

Comment: Fantastic my friend you helped me, Thank You. Was searching for this from past 4 days. Thank You. Guys its works!!!

Comment: This worked for me too!  (I also restarted Xcode using 'open myproject.xcworkspace after installing Pods in case that matters)

Comment: When I switch my scheme back to my app scheme, this no longer works.  Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 33):

This may fix your problem:

1. Quit the Xcode. (Don't just close the Xcode window, right click and Quit it explicitly).
2. Go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete the project folder. (Simply delete all the folders).
3. Clean and Build the project.

If still error exist:

Do steps 1 and 2 and follow this steps:

4. Change scheme to Firebase and Build (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>).
5. Change back to your app scheme and Run again.

Comment: The above steps didnt solve my issue, please help me.

Comment: Please try other answers. Your case can be different.

Answer (score 20):

I opened the project with .xcodeproj and I installed Firebase with cocoapods. I got the same error. But I just close the project and open it with .xcworkspace.

The alert has gone. Firebase was the first library on my project. So I kept using .xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 14):

Install FireBase properly via **CocoaPods**. Try the following steps

Step 1 - Close Xcode

Step 2 - Clear your derived data. You can find your derived data in here

> **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**

Step 3 - Open your .xcworkspace

Step 4 - Clean your project (**⌘+Shift+K**)

Step 5 - Build your project (**⌘+B**)

***Make sure your are opened .xcworkspace file***

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me using Xcode 9.4 on Ionic 3 app.

Answer (score 8):

For me the issue was simple. I have a new m1 mac and it has trouble loading cocoa pods sometimes. Simply:

- Click your pods project(blue pods)->
- Click all & build settings ->
- Excluded architectures ->
- add "arm64" to both debug and release ->
- set any SDK on left side ->
- do this on your main project folder too ->
- build it your good to go

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on my M1 Pro device. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Zach Gonzalez. I have this exact same problem and I'm getting nuts. I have an M1 Mac and every time I build I see different compile error, and many of them are related to CocoaPods. I've done exactly what you say but the problem persists. To give an example: AWSDynamoDBModel > Could not build module 'AWSCore'. I tried Clean & Rebuild many times, I've also tried pod install + pod update to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: This should be the right answer for Xcode 13 M1 also

Comment: Working solution for XCode 14.1 on M1 Pro Mac. It's essential to add "arm64" to "Excluded Architectures" on both the Main project and the Pods project, otherwise it won't work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

'pod deintegrate' and then 'pod install' worked for me.

Comment: tried many other solutions. But this one worked. Really helped.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this problem when using Xcode 12. I found that removing the Valid Architectures build setting (VALID_ARCHS) fixed it.

From the [Xcode 12](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes) release notes:

> The Build Settings editor no longer includes the Valid Architectures build setting (VALID_ARCHS), and its use is discouraged. Instead, there is a new Excluded Architectures build setting (EXCLUDED_ARCHS). If a project includes VALID_ARCHS, the setting is displayed in the User-Defined section of the Build Settings editor. (15145028)

Answer (score 4):

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.4.  This helped solve the same issue for me.

I selected the following frameworks in XCode -> Manage Schemes besides my target project

In Xcode:

```
Product-> Scheme-> FirebaseCore
Product -> Scheme -> nanopb
Product -> Scheme -> GoogleToolBoxforMac
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried the above suggestions, but they didn't work for me. What worked for me was to build to `Generic iOS Device` first and then run it on my physical device iPhone6.

I still couldn't run it on a simulator, however. What worked here was to change `Build Active Architecture Only - Debug` to `NO`, in the `Pod Project Build Settings`.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank YOU @marceh , this helped me. After trying the steps above it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Close Xcode
2. pod deintegrate
3. delete xcworkspace
4. pod install
5. In project Navigator > project name > Configurations
6. Set all to none
7. Clean
8. Build

Answer (score 4):

I had disabled **Find Implicit Dependencies** for faster build process under `Edit Scheme... > Build`.

Enabling it back resolved the issue.
[image]

Comment: Product => Edit Scheme... Short cut is   command + <

Comment: this worked for me too. I disabled "Find implicit Dependencies" and build was working fine too, I recently got this issue after updating the xcode. Error gone by enabling this option again on the new updated xCode.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me because I installed the Firebase CocoaPods but I didn't reopen it through the `<projectName>.xcworkspace` file.
So what I did to work was:

- I quit Xcode
- opened it by clicking the `<projectName>.xcworkspace` file of the project
- then I could use "import Firebase" on my project.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try to take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44412936/4887400)

**TL;DR** make sure you are running cocoapods version `1.4.0 minimum`. It fixes static framework imports.

You can do this by running `sudo gem install cocoapods` on your terminal and verify your version by typing `pod --version`

Answer (score 3):

I tried this (quitting Xcode, deleting all temp files, reinstalling pods, etc.) and it didn't work. What did work was just building my project (`command + b`) after `pod install`. Whatever works!

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure** you are working with the **workspace file** created in the same directory as the pod file.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me, when I opened the white workspace instead of the blue one. You press on the file on your desktop and then press the white file.

Image of what the file looks like:
[image: Image of what the file looks like]

Answer (score 1):

Just go to **Pod target** and set **arm64** in **Excluded Architectures**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue with a Flutter project.

You should exclude arm64 for simulator architecture both from project and every pod target

**Exclude arm64 from the project**

[image: Excluded Architectures]

**Add this code to Pofile**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    # exclude arm64 for simulator architecture the pod target
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

just restart your xcode and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here worked for me, but then I figured out something that did work.

When I clicked on my project in Project Navigator in Xcode, and then selected **Info** I looked at the **Configurations** section and saw that there was only a **Release** configuration and no **Debug** configuration for my app.

In order to get Firebase to work, I went to **Pods** within the Project Navigator, and under the **Configurations** section I deleted the **Debug** configuration. Now it builds fine. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of searching and trying every single step proposed in this post, eventually i could solve the problem. None of the above approaches solved my problem but this one:

1. There is a package of Firebase frameworks available to download from this link:
   https://firebase.google.com/download/ios?authuser=0
2. There is a Firebase.h header file in this package. I added this header file to my project resources.
3. Finally i added a line of code at the top of this file:
   ' #import "Firebase.h" '

Simply and Easily the error is gone!

Comment: where do you add the Firebase.h file and where do you add the import statement? I've been struggling with this for days. everything builds and works fine but when I add the Firebase iOS SDK (FirebaseAnalytics) the project fails to build. this seems to be the answer but I'm confused as to how you managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For and Solution was as simple as I didn't open the project from the .xcworkspace after I did pod install :D and I got the same error you got.
I mistakenly opened it from the old .xcodeproj file.
that was it for me, LOL

Answer (score 0):

None of above solutions worked for me. I found that the problem was I have three targets in Cocoapods file. And only my main one target has Firebase added. So that when I want to import Firebase to a file that is used in other targets, Xcode gives error and says Module 'Firebase' not found. This is my pods project file. One solution for me is adding Firebase pod to all targets. Or another solution is removing the file from other targets.

```html
def common_pods
  pod 'XXX'
end

target 'myMainProject' do
  common_pods()
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end

target 'myExtention1' do
  common_pods()
end

target 'myextension2' do
  common_pods()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> This solution worked for me.

1. Delete project's temp files located at
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
2. Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
3. Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder Run pod install.
4. Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me today, I just couldn't figure out why, because when I closed the file that night, everything was perfect. I opened my file using the recent projects menu and got this issue. Then I decided to check something, Xcode opened the wrong file. Instead of opening the workspace file with the pods, it opened the Xcode project.

Once I opened the workspace it was error free and all the pods were behaving. Im sure you guys are all more experienced than me, but I just wanted to throw that in there.

Answer (score -1):

When you build, make sure you are at the root directory in the project navigator.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

- rm -rf project.xcworkspace
- rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- rm -rf Podfile.lock
- pod install

/!\ Open project.xcworkspace instead of your old file

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact same issue

You could be reinstalling pods with your Xcode open
Or your pods file won't allow and overwrite

With your workspace open, delete the "Pods" folder.
Quit X-Code
Open terminal in "Utilities" 
You'll find this in "Applications"
Using cd ... go to your project folder
reinstall pods using "pod install".

That should fix it.