# Could not build module Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have been trying to wire up Firebase analytics into a Objective C/Swift project. I have followed the instructions properly.  My search paths are set. My linker flags is set to -ObjC.  I can get the project to compile properly.  As soon a I @import Firebase and build, I get an error that says cannot build Firebase module.  When I look into the logs I see there is a parse issue building Firebase analytics and Firebase Core.  I have wired this into three other projects fine not using cocoa pods. Please advise.

Comment: Hi. Please post relevant code snippets and any other useful data (e.g. logs). :)

Comment: Are you opening the xcworkspace file with Xcode instead of the xcproject?

Comment: @AL There are no code snippet as of yet this is just a build issue. The only code of I have but in place is import Firebase. The logs I see for the build issue in Xcode are **Parse Issue:  Could not build module FirebaseCore while building module Firebase Analytics in File included from <module-includes>:1: in file included from FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FirebaseAnalytics.h**  this error is followed by  **Could not build module FirbaseAnalytics**

Comment: @PaulBeusterien  I have been opening the workspace file. But only adding files to the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue and tried everything possible:

```
- (Checked that I was actually using .xcworkspace instead of .xcproj)
- Deleted Derived Data
- Cleaned Pods folder, deleted Podfile.lock, pod deintegrate and pod install / update again
- Deleted cached file everywhere on my mac (including hidden folders in Library/Caches/Cocoapods), /var/folders etc.
- Deleted the project, uninstalled Xcode, reinstalled, cloned again etc.
- Check all Build Settings in Xcode, desperately tried all options
```

Nothing worked.

The only solution (and the correct one) was to run a `sudo gem install cocoapods` to go from `1.2.0` to `1.2.1`.

Indeed, you can see that in the changelog for 1.2.1 there is [this pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6477) that fixes import issues with vendor frameworks

**TL;DR** If you are running cocoapods 1.2.0, you will want to run `sudo gem install cocoapods`and make sure you are at least running 1.2.1.

You can check your version by typing `pod --version` anywhere on your terminal.

Comment: minimum required version is now CocoaPods 1.4.0. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to install cocoapods.
I am using M1 macbook with xcode 12.4. i was facing the same issue.

This worked for me:

- rm -rf project.xcworkspace
- rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- rm -rf Podfile.lock
- sudo gem install cocoapods
- pod install

/!\ Open project.xcworkspace instead of your old file