# Firebase Cocoapods - Error message; Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, module, cocoapods

I'm trying to import Firebase after installing Cocoapods via terminal but i'm getting the following error message:

> Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase

Can someone help me out with this?

This is my Podfile content:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Login_test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Login_test
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be enough detail for anyone to provide a useful answer.  Describe what you did and what happened.

Comment: Try Shift+Option+Command+K to clean the build folder and rebuild again. Additionally, you might want to post your Podfile.

Comment: Paul Beusterien, See the steps that i've taken below:

1. I've installed Firebase with Cocoapods using the terminal according to the following installation video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEAjvNRdZa0&spfreload=10

2. I tried to import the Module in Xcode and it gave me this error. Also when i try to build the app with the simulator i'm getting the error that it can't find FirebaseAnalytics.

Comment: check this answer. i fixed my issue with those steps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69503768/9437421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed FireBase properly via CocoaPods. Try the following steps

Step 1 - Close Xcode

Step 2 - Clear your derived data. You can find your derived data in here

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Step 3 - Open your **.xcworkspace**

Step 4 - **Clean** your project (⌘+Shift+K)

Step 5 - **Build** your project (⌘+B)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not help. I get the same error message.  Error message; Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase. Also when i try to build the app i get the following error message: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). When i reveal it in Log i see the following: Framework not found Firebaseanalytics.

Comment: Can you install firebase again with cocoapods and try again? It will be great if you show us your Podfile contents.

Comment: Hi Rizwan, 

This is my Podfile content:                                                    

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Login_test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Login_test
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
end

Comment: Do you also have the correct info instructions for installing cocoapods and Firebase?  See my Podfile contents in my question at the top!

Comment: @ChikeKotzebue Try installing the Firebase pod with updated cocoapods (v1.5.0 or higher). Cocoapods team has released a new version of cocoapods now.

Answer (score 3):

for beginners:

make sure you read the message after installing the Pod, 
you need to `close` the xcode project and use the `.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

Comment: :) awsome! it was a small detail missing from the other solutions I was finding online as well, so odd, it was right in front of us 

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was simple. I have a new m1 mac and it has trouble loading cocoa pods sometimes. Simply click your pods project(blue pods)->Click all & build settings ->Excluded architectures -> add "arm64" to both debug and release -> set any SDK on left side -> do this on your main project folder too -> build it your good to go

[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEuZv.png)