# Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' // FirebaseAnalytics.h not found

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

Fired up my Project this day, added the Analytics pod and now nothing seems to work anymore... Any ideas? Already delted DerivedData and stuff...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase)

Comment: See the link re deleting .xcworkspace, pods, and running a fresh pod install

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Install FireBase properly via CocoaPods. Try the following steps (After pod init and pod install command, you should close the currently opened project and reopen your project with **.xcworkspace**)

Step 1 - Close Xcode

Step 2 - Clear your derived data. You can find your derived data in here

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Step 3 - Open your .xcworkspace

Step 4 - Clean your project (⌘+Shift+K)

Step 5 - Build your project (⌘+B)

***Make sure your are opened .xcworkspace file***