# Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' - swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

This seems like a rehash of this question..
[Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase)

I am doing a swift project for starters.
but I have never had this problem before... What has changed is that a number of updates have been made to Firebase in the last couple of days including the addition of MLFirebase.  So... I am suspicious that something may have happened.

I followed all of the instruction in the article mentioned above... but no joy.  I have also updated my pods to...1.5.2
I've done a pod update

and I am starting from a brand new project in xCode.

is anyone else having this issue?  And other than above article, how are you resolving it?

Comment: Just to check, are you installing Firebase via cocoapods?

Comment: Yes... I am using Pod init...   Pod install...  doing everything as explained in Firebase Registration Screen...  I've done this procedure before about 500 times.. and nothing like this.  The only change...  addition of new Firebase pods for ML.  I was having the problem before I upgraded pods as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what I did to resolve this, but I just did a couple clean then builds and it worked.  The error resolved itself.