# Firebase Database reference is giving me an error

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have imported the Firebase .plist into my project and also all the relevant pods such as: (Firebase, FirebaseDatabase, FirebaseAuth, FirebaseCore, FirebaseInstanceID) but, I'm still getting this error even though my code is similar to the one in [Firebase's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start).

[image]

What is the problem?

Edit: Actual code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        let myDatabase = Database.database().reference()  <- Error

        return true
    }
```

Error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'Database'`

**EDIT2:** I solved the issue by [following these steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486792/8177581)

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Try defining your  reference in using `FIRDatabase` like this: `let myDatabase = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` this method has worked for me.

Comment: @HaydenCrabb That's an older version. You may want to update your pod