# Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' with Swift 5

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, xcode10, ios12, swift5

I want to use Firebase with Swift 5, but error message appears.

> Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

I tried all resolutions on below pages, but I can't solve it:

[Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase)

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/672

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

I expect Build Success, but actually Build Failed.

Build error messages are:

> 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
>   Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

And, xcode shows Error message at

```
import Firebase
```

in AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My business partner solves this issue.

The resolution is below steps:

1. Quite xcode
2. Delete "ProjectName.xcworkspace", "Podfile.lock" and "Pods".
3. Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData (Command + Shift + G in finder)
4. Run "pod install" from terminal.
5. Open "ProjectName.xcworkspace".
6. Add "$(inherited)" to "TARGET > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths".

Comment: Searched through other answers and deleting Pods folder was what was missing. Spent few hours trying so thanks. Also, For me I needed to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" as always.

Comment: Not Working for me in Xcode 12.4 . Earlier it was working fine with Xcode 11.

Comment: Not working for me as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Pod deintegrate.
2. Delete xcworkspace file.
3. Open terminal with Rosetta.
4. Install pods.