# No such module 'ARGear'?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I added https://docs.argear.io/ios/argear-sdk-initialization-and-extinction-glview-initialization framework to my Xcode by dragging the framework into the frameworks folder

**And yet when I try to import the library I get the error, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?**

```
import ARGear //error
```

> No such module 'ARGear'

project:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `import ARGear`

Comment: @toto at first I thought this had worked but after doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836042/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase-with-swift-5 to fix another issue it now has the same issue as before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a framework by dragging, please make sure the following are being selected.

Distination: Copy items if needed

Added folders: Create folder references

https://i.stack.imgur.com/byc9A.png

Comment: Thank you for answering. It would improve the quality of the answer exponentially if you were a bit more descriptive on the steps to be followed without assuming that the OP is aware of where the options you took a screenshot of are located.