# XCode 12 : 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found and Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

Tags: firebase, swift5, ios14, xcode12

My iOS project is working fine in Xcode 11.2.1.
When I'm trying to run it with Xcode 12.4 then I'm not able to run it.

I installed Firebase through cocoapods and below is the Podfile content.

```
pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
  pod 'FirebaseDynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

I tried the steps according to some suggestion -

1. Quit Xcode.
   2.  Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   3.  Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
   4.  Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
   5.  Run pod install.
   6.  Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

But it is not working for me.

Please give Some suggestion on that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI or building for macOS?

Comment: no @udbhateja I'm not using swiftUi and not building for macOS.

Comment: Will you please post the error

Comment: Hi @udbhateja , 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found and Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' under the Swift compiler error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836042/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase-with-swift-5

Comment: @udbhateja, Already tried with this link but it's not working.