# Could not build a module

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

I have faced with such error while building the project:

> Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.4.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:25:10: error: could not build module 'Darwin'

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486792/8374890

Comment: No I trying with creating of new application also issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in two ways.

1)/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

go to that path and replace the frameworks folder from another mac on which xcode is installed.

2)clean that and build again and again might solve your problem.

Comment: No I already replace the Framework folder from the new system with same version Xcode also issue is not fixed.