# Podfile won't update after mac update to Catalina, Reason: image not found

Tags: swift, podfile

I recently updated my mac to Catalina and since, the Podfile for one of my projects is crashing when I try to install/update it (the Podfile).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        20: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
        19: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        18: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
        17: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        16: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        15: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        14: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:75:in `<module:Pod>'
        13: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        12: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         9: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         6: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/typhoeus-1.3.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/digest/sha2.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/sha2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/sha2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/sha2.bundle
```

What I understand from this traceback message is that the reference for one of the files is not correct but I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried boiling down my Podfile to the essentials but the error still persists. This is the Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.2'
target 'ShoeSwiperMenus' do
end
```

I tried following [this step by step process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase) thinking it could help but it didn't.

When running `sudo gem install cocoapods`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: did you try updating your cocoaPods?  `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Hi Keshu, thanks for your answer. No I had not, however, I get an error when I do. I'll add it to the end of the question

Comment: Your ruby is broken, and OpenSSL is always problematic. I recommend removing and reinstalling homebrew, using rbenv to control your ruby version, updating ruby, and installing gems from scratch. However, none of this is a programming matter so I suggest moving it to Ask Different.

Comment: Hi Matt, okay I'll do that and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn’t your Podfile install any pods?

Comment: I wanted to make sure it wasn't the pods which were causing the problem so I took them out

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @matt, I solved this pretty quickly. As he pointed out, my ruby was broken. These are the steps I took to solve this:

Install the Ruby Version Manager rvm: `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Install the latest version of Ruby: `rvm install ruby-[version]`
In my case this was: `rvm install ruby-2.7`

Then: `rvm use ruby-2.7`

And:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```