# 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found while building for Release Mode in Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to run the app in Debug mode in XCODE and simulator without any errors. But when I build for Release Mode the build fails with below 2 errors:

1. 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
2. Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

I have been trying different solutions available on Stackoverflow and gitHub over last 10 days but know seems to be working, below are the details.

**FLUTTER DOCTOR :**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**POD FILE :**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

**AppDelegate.swift (file) :**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
  FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

**Firebase.h file (Path: Pods>Pods>Firebase>CoreOnly>Firebase.h) :**

```
// Copyright 2019 Google
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>

#if !defined(__has_include)
  #error "Firebase.h won't import anything if your compiler doesn't support __has_include. Please \
          import the headers individually."
#else
  #if __has_include(<FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>)
    #import <FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>)
    #import <FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.h>)
    #import <FirebaseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h>)
    #import <FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseDynamicLinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks.h>)
    #import <FirebaseDynamicLinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks.h>
    #if !__has_include(<FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>)
      #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure \
Firebase Dynamic Links works as intended."
      #endif // #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
    #endif
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.h>)
    #import <FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseFunctions/FirebaseFunctions.h>)
    #import <FirebaseFunctions/FirebaseFunctions.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseInAppMessaging/FirebaseInAppMessaging.h>)
    #import <FirebaseInAppMessaging/FirebaseInAppMessaging.h>
    #if !__has_include(<FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>)
      #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure \
Firebase In App Messaging works as intended."
      #endif // #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
    #endif
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h>)
    #import <FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h>
      #if !__has_include(<FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>)
      #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure \
Firebase Messaging works as intended."
      #endif // #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
    #endif
#endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLCommon/FirebaseMLCommon.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLCommon/FirebaseMLCommon.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLModelInterpreter/FirebaseMLModelInterpreter.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLModelInterpreter/FirebaseMLModelInterpreter.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLNLLanguageID/FirebaseMLNLLanguageID.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLNLLanguageID/FirebaseMLNLLanguageID.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLNLSmartReply/FirebaseMLNLSmartReply.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLNLSmartReply/FirebaseMLNLSmartReply.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLNLTranslate/FirebaseMLNLTranslate.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLNLTranslate/FirebaseMLNLTranslate.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLNaturalLanguage/FirebaseMLNaturalLanguage.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLNaturalLanguage/FirebaseMLNaturalLanguage.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVision/FirebaseMLVision.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVision/FirebaseMLVision.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionAutoML/FirebaseMLVisionAutoML.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVisionAutoML/FirebaseMLVisionAutoML.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel/FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel/FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel/FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel/FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionLabelModel/FirebaseMLVisionLabelModel.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVisionLabelModel/FirebaseMLVisionLabelModel.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionObjectDetection/FirebaseMLVisionObjectDetection.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVisionObjectDetection/FirebaseMLVisionObjectDetection.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionTextModel/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.h>)
    #import <FirebaseMLVisionTextModel/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebasePerformance/FirebasePerformance.h>)
    #import <FirebasePerformance/FirebasePerformance.h>
    #if !__has_include(<FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>)
      #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure \
Firebase Performance works as intended."
      #endif // #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
    #endif
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseRemoteConfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.h>)
    #import <FirebaseRemoteConfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.h>
    #if !__has_include(<FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>)
      #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
        #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
`Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure \
Firebase Remote Config works as intended."
      #endif // #ifndef FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_SUPPRESS_WARNING
    #endif
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage.h>)
    #import <FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>)
    #import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<Fabric/Fabric.h>)
    #import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
  #endif

  #if __has_include(<Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>)
    #import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
  #endif

#endif  // defined(__has_include)
```

> Firebase.h error

[image: Firebase.h error]

> Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

[image: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase']

Comment: Hey @Rohit have you tried to uninstall and install the pod manually?

Comment: @Rohit Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing same issue, in my case Firebase pods version issue was there. I fixed that though following steps:-

1. First comment all the pods related with Firebase.
2. Copy the project path and paste on terminal.
3. Now run `pod install`, this will remove all the pods related with Firebase
4. Now open your podFile and uncomment all the pods related to Firebase.
5. Open your project. Now clean your project folder and run the app.

Comment: Not sure I understand it, but this actually works. Uninstalling the Firebase pods and reinstalling them fixes the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: This one worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue, this can help you.

```
to replace FirebaseCore to "FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h"
```

[image: you can see the image]

Answer (score 1):

This migration guide for react-native-firebase could be useful for your case:

https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6#removing-v5-from-javascript

I uninstalled version 5 and installed version 6, but it seems there was some extra work to do to get rid of older versions of firebase.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
My mistake was not setting the device to build for to `Any iOS Device`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've opened your project's `.xcworkspace` file, rather than the `.xcodeproj` file - as that will load all of your Pods as well, which can overcome edge-case errors like the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix the issue by opening the .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproj using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

`#import <Firebase.h>`
Add the above line in `AppDelegate.h`.
It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Let's go step by step.

1 - 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found.

For this error, you can try to comment `use_frameworks` in `podfile`. The related part of the podfile will look like this:

```
   target 'Runner' do
     #use_frameworks!
     use_modular_headers!
```

There is a similar issue for React Native, mentioned in [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1166).

2 - Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

This is a common issue related to the project's temp files. You need to delete this. Follow these steps as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486792/10659482):

> 1- Quit Xcode.
>
> 2- Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
>
> 3- Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
>
> 4- Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
>
> 5- Run pod install.
>
> 6- Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.