# Xcode12 file not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode12

Just updated my project to Xcode12 and tried to compile. I keep getting "file not found" errors for multiple modules from the pods included in my project.

I tried to follow these instructions mentioned here but that didn't work.
[Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase)

I still see this error

[image]

Btw, this error isn't specific to just Firebase. My project is mostly objective c with some swift files.

Any thoughts on how to fix this ?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi/64016147#64016147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the 'Build Active Architecture' to NO in the pods project fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Build System can fix the errors. On your Xcode Workspace, Go File -> Workspace Settings. Then change to "Legacy Build System".

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help. Setting the active arch to NO in pods did the trick for me.

Comment: Yes posted my answer above

Answer (score 0):

See my explanation, which contains the second section that can help by some Podfile attachment:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = 
  "arm64"
  end
end
```

and some project configurations, for more info go to:

https://github.com/ElizaSapir/KnowlageSharing/blob/main/Xcode12Issues.md