# could not build Objective-C module 'flutter_freshchat'(Not able to take iOS build)

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

In one of my project Iam using [flutter_freshchat](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_freshchat) integration. In that am facing an issue in iOS, when I add flutter_freshchat: ^1.3.0 in pubspec.yaml. Am not able to build only with this. Am getting error the following;

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:#import "Headers/flutter_freshchat-umbrella.h"        ^/Users/docty/Workspace/Projects/Docty/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_freshchat/flutter_freshchat-umbrella.h:13:9: note: in file included from /Users/docty/Workspace/Projects/Docty/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_freshchat/flutter_freshchat-umbrella.h:13:#import "FlutterFreshchatPlugin.h"        ^/Users/docty/Workspace/FlutterDevelopments/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter_freshchat-37d8d569f7adc8c6451384634386f1151b1d686f/ios/Classes/FlutterFreshchatPlugin.h:2:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'flutter_freshchat.FlutterFreshchatPlugin': '/Users/docty/Workspace/Projects/Docty/ios/Pods/FreshchatSDK/FreshchatSDK/FreshchatSDK.h'#import "FreshchatSDK.h"        ^<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'flutter_freshchat'
```

But when I use the workaround like the following link I am able to build.

[fix](https://github.com/fayeed/flutter_freshchat/issues/34#issuecomment-618804254)

That time I have to remove the domain from FlutterFreshchat.init. But without a domain it's not loading the data also. May I know why I am getting this kind of issue. Struggling from past one week. I tried all the git issues solution. It's not working.

**Flutter details:**

Flutter 1.22.3 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 8874f21e79 (7 months ago) • 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700
Engine • revision a1440ca392
Tools • Dart 2.10.3

**Xcode details:**
Version 12.5

Issues

[image: issue]

[image: issue1]

Comment: Hope you have already try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase

Comment: Kindly check the iOS section of [flutter_freshchat](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_freshchat)'s documentation. That might be helpful