# Facebook Login swift No such module

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have imported facebook sdk via Cocoa Pods, described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

But weirdly, when I use it on my device, I get :

> No suche module FacebookLogin

On the emulator it's working....

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let fbLoginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        fbLoginButton.center = view.center

        view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)

    }
}
```

My pod file :

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myapp' do
  pod 'SwiftEventBus', :tag => '2.2.0', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'
  pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed from

> platform :ios, '8.0'

to

> platform :ios, '10.0'

in my podfile

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just have added them here and it worked

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Facebook somehow forgot this important thing in their doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have CocoaPod installed in your Mac?
2. Did you install Pods in the directory the Xcode Project is in?

These both can be installed with this link. [How to Install Pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418062/how-to-run-pod-install-in-project-directory)

> - Open Terminal.
> - If you haven't already done so, run this command: `sudo gem install cocoapods` Wait for it to finish before proceeding.
> - Find the project directory in the Finder. This should be the folder that has the Xcode  project in it.
> - Type `cd` into the terminal, followed by a space.
> - Drag and drop the project directory into the terminal window.
> - It should now say something like this: cd /Users/someone/Downloads/WonderfulProject
> - Press return.
> - Now type `pod install`. Wait for that to finish. It could take a while.
>
> Done!

Comment: The question is about the problem with facebook login even necessary frameworks are installed using cocoapods, not about using cocoapods in the iOS project

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `pod 'FacebookLogin'` to your Podfile and install it using pod

then the `import FacebookLogin` will work like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

I achieved Facebook Login last week. It is working on device and emulator. 
What I did was simply add those frameworks from profile in Xcode instead of cocopod.